# A word to describe the state of having been the first to do something

Tags: word-request

If someone was the first to do something, which then became widespread and fashionable, and then claims that they were the first to do so, what would we say:

"Their claim to [or "of"] XXXXX"?

I thought of "primacy"?

Or "anteriority," but this seems a relative notion to me when I would like it to be in absolute.

"Paternity" is not good either, because this person would not even have had to generate the fashion, only to have been the first to do this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Priority" would be a common word here.

> Newton's claim of priority over Leibniz was disputed by continental mathematicians.

"Primacy" refers to being the most important.  Paternity is about fatherhood, perhaps metaphorically. I don't recognise the word anteriority

Comment: Thank you very much, I think it is the exact word I was looking for! Two additional questions: 1/ Couldn't this word also be understood as "being the most important," (which doesn't matter much since it will be clear from the context) 2/ Are "claim of priority" and "priority claim" both correct? Thanks

Comment: It might be used to mean "most important" so provide context.  In the given context I'd prefer "claim of priority". You could also use claim as a verb  "Newton claimed priority over Leibniz for the invention of calculus.

Comment: ***High priority*** tasks are the most *urgent* jobs. But the allusion in ***to claim priority*** is to having a ***prior claim*** (an ***earlier*** claim).